# Use Apache 2.4 on MAMP PRO 5.x

Tags: apache, mamp, tls1.2, mamp-pro

I need to run Apache 2.4 on MAMP PRO 5.x but the company that makes MAMP issues the following statement:

**You can only run the MAMP PRO components with the included Apache 2.2 . We will be upgrading to Apache 2.4 in MAMP PRO 6, which will be available in 2020.**

Has anyone figured out a workaround? I need to be using TLS 1.2 and per some other posts I found, i.e. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206901/using-mamp-3-4-how-do-i-upgrade-to-apache-2-4-and-openssl-1-0-2-to-meet-the-ats

They mention:

**TLS 1.2 works only with apache 2.4**

We are planning on transitioning away from MAMP in favor of homestead or vagrant, but for the current build we would like to figure out a way to use Apache 2.4 (for the sole purposes of using TLS 1.2) without changing our local development environments.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats just the way it goes when you use a packaged system like MAMP PRO, it is up to them if they want to support Apache 2.4 or not, and it sounds like they will, but just not when it suits you.  I also use MAMP 5 and want Apache 2.4, but looks like I will have to suck it up and run my own Apache 2.4 server too.

That said, there might be a way to hack MAMP PRO to work with another local version of Apache, but it would be unlikely you would receive any support from MAMP PRO in trying to get it to work